# WPF Taskbar Restore/Minimize doesn't always work

Tags: wpf, restore, taskbar

So I have a large WPF application, and there is an icon on the taskbar when the application is running. I would expect that if I click the taskbar icon, the application will restore itself, or minimize if it is already showing, as is standard windows functionality. However, sometimes I have to click several times for this to work. I've done quite a bit of research/programming, but this is one fairly simple item I can not figure out. Any help is appreciated, please let me know if I need to provide more info. I have tested using a jumplist, but my users do not want to right click the icon and then click "restore". They just want to left-click the taskbar icon. .Net 4.0, WPF 4. Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: post a simple example where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I would love to, but I can't reproduce the issue. Every WPF app I create works perfect, it's only this solution that seems to have issues.

Comment: then extract the pieces from that solution into another solution (main window, etc) and see if the problem reproduces.

Comment: I tried that, but still had the issue. I figured it may be due to a threading issue, handling a mouse event that may be interfering, but still looking for a solution,or at least an idea of what else could be interfering with this out of the box functionality.