# WPF child window doesn't consistently restore after being minimized

Tags: c#, wpf

The setup I have is a 'MainWindow', then there is another window which opens, we'll call it 'ChildWindow', the owner of ChildWindow is MainWindow, meaning whilst the ChildWindow is open, if you click on something on the MainWindow, ChildWindow won't be put behind the MainWindow, it will always stay on top of the MainWindow.

When the ChildWindow is maximized, then minimized, occasionally when trying to restore the window (through either the taskbar, or 'restore'), it won't restore itself - when this does happen, the ChildWindow sometimes flashes up for a brief moment and then quickly goes away again.

Before asking for an example, or voting to close, PLEASE take note of the following:

- I cannot reproduce this issue on my development machine (which is the only one I currently have access to).
- This seems to happen on almost every other PC than mine.
- I can't recreate this issue from a new WPF application whatever I seem to do.
- The program I am working on is HUGE, and it would take considerable time and effort to strip down the code in both affected windows to try to get this to reproduce with a smaller amount of code (and bear in mind even after stripping it down, I still can't verify the issue happens on my development PC).
- It is against company policy to release code (apart from small snippets).

My issue is the same (or very similar) to these issues:

[WPF Taskbar Restore/Minimize doesn't always work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986288/wpf-taskbar-restore-minimize-doesnt-always-work)

[Unable to consistently restore minimized WPF application](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/321902/Unable-to-consistently-restore-minimized-WPF-appli)

I genuinely have no direction on what I should be looking for, and I know that without an example, this question IS going to be very difficult to solve (but isn't that what this site's for?), but if anyone experienced in WPF could offer any insight into what COULD cause an issue like this so I can narrow down my field of search, I can then start to paste in the smaller related snippets of code into my question to help get to the bottom of this issue.

If anyone can link me to a forum site with atleast half the users of SO I'd be happy to post there instead - but right now this feels like the best place.

**EDIT** - The following code is used to set the MainWindow as the owner of the ChildWindow (this code is inside the ChildWindow.xaml.cs):

```
public void ShowDisplay(Window ownerWindow)
{
    Owner = ownerWindow;
    Show();
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide the following info: 1) are multiple displays involved, and if so, are they set up in a static scenario or are they like laptops, plugging in and out displays all the time? 2) is the task bar at the default windows location (bottom)? Next: without the code you are using to trigger this restore and hide functionality it's hard to give a solution other than guessing, and that's not what this site is about ;-)

Comment: Also, are you triggering some updates on the main window periodically? Or is there a modal dialog somewhere?

Comment: @Stefan thanks for the response! On my development PC, I am using a laptop dock which plugs into multiple monitors, but it's just occurred to me that on the machines where this does happen, it has always so far been a single monitor. As for the taskbar, it is on the bottom. I'll see if I can grab the code for the restore and hide functionality :)

Comment: @Stefan in your second response are you suggesting that this could be the MainWindow triggering focus back to itself (by chance) at the moment you try to restore the sub-window? And I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'modal dialog'

Comment: @Stefan the restore and hide functionality does appear to just be the default windows 'minimize' button and restore from taskbar - there is no code that interferes with the process of minimizing and restoring.

Comment: @Stefan I just checked out what 'modal dialog' meant, and we don't have any open at the time when this issue occurs. ChildWindow stays in front of the MainWindow all the time (unless minimized), but you can still click on the window behind.

Comment: `MainWindow triggering focus back to itself (by chance) at the moment you try to restore the sub-window`, yes, sometimes UI updates can trigger focus in some ways. Think of it as when you try to install an application... while installing you continue work... sometimes... when the installation is done, a window forces itself to the foreground (pretty anoying btw), but still, something like that can be the case.

Comment: @Stefan thanks, I'll investigate this and post back here if I find anything.